# change pagination link in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I am getting pagination links like -> /page/3. But i would like to change this "page" to "news". Is it possible?
Thank you!

```
echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big2, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big2 ) ) ),
'format'  => '?paged1=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged1') ),
'total'   => $news->max_num_pages,
'mid_size' => 0,
'type' => 'plain',
'end_size'=>0,
'prev_text' => '&lt;IEPREKŠĒJĀ LAPA',
'next_text' => 'NĀKOŠĀ LAPA&gt;'
 ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function my_custom_pagination_base() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = 'p'; //where new-slug is the slug you want to use 
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'my_custom_pagination_base', 1);
```

Comment: Can you please add the details on why this would solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change pagination base using below code

```
    <?php
    add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_page_word' );
    function my_custom_page_word() {
      global $wp_rewrite;  // Get the global wordpress rewrite-rules/settings

      // Change the base pagination property which sets the wordpress pagination slug.
      $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = "news";  //where new-slug is the slug you want to use ;)
    }
   ?>
```

For reference you can refer below link

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57070/change-the-page-slug-in-pagination

Comment: Thank you very much.I have such weird design, there are two paginations on the same page. I would like first leave as "page", and second one change to 'news'.

Answer (score 0):

To remove `page` or whatever your base is set to for your pagination do the following.

First add the following to `functions.php`. This function will rewrite our base pagination prefix to and empty string.

```
function my_custom_pagination_base() {
global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = ''; 
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'my_custom_pagination_base', 1);
```

Second we add the our `paginate_links()` function to our archives page. with the following arguments. Make sure base is not set, or it will mess up our rewrite function.

```
echo paginate_links(array(
     'format' => '\\%#%/',
     'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
     'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages
));
```

Set your `current` and `total` args to whatever you need them to be.
Your archive pagination url should look like `www.site.com/some-category/2/` when you go to page 2