# Change pagination base slug on WooCommerce archive product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, pagination, permalinks, slug

I want to change pagination slug, currently 'page' to 'strana' on WooCommerce archive pages.

Default setting with urls `http://localhost/obchod/` and `http://localhost/obchod/page/2/` works fine.
When I change pagination base and resave permalinks it not works.
Final url should look like: `http://localhost/obchod/strana/2/`

This is my code for changing the pagination base:

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = 'strana';
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

I always resave permalinks on WordPress or I use `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();`, but non of these works.

Note that this code works for WordPress pagination, but **not for WooCommerce pagination shop pages**.

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change pagination link in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822928/change-pagination-link-in-wordpress)

Comment: Mr. Jo, this not solve my problem. This works only for WordPress, but pagination on WooCommerce archive product page still doesn't work.

Comment: What is obchod in your link http://localhost/obchod/ ? Its folder for wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

First we need to change the format of the links that Wordpress generates. As we need to change the pagination format only for the shop archive, we add a conditional tag is_shop() , so another pagination will stay in old format.

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
global $wp_rewrite;
if(is_shop()) {
$wp_rewrite->pagination_base = 'strana';
}
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

Next, we add_rewrite_rule() to make Wordpress understand the new link format for pagination pages

```
add_rewrite_rule(
'^obchod/strana/([^/]+)/?',
'index.php?paged=$matches[1]',
'top'
);
```

obchod here = your shop base, default its shop fow woocommerce stores

Update for test

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->pagination_base = 'strana';

}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');

add_rewrite_rule(
'^obchod/strana/([^/]+)/?',
'index.php?paged=$matches[1]&post_type=product',
'top'
);
```

Comment: Thanks Orbital, it not works correctly. This will redirect from `http://localhost/obchod/strana/2/` into `http://localhost/page/2/`. So it redirects to homepage with page 2. And yes you are right, obchod is the shop base.

Comment: Disable/enable permalinks on yor wordpess to clear rewrite cache. I tested this on my demo, its work 100%

Comment: What your permalink structure ? can you screen this admin page ?

Comment: Try update for test, and disable/enable permalinks on yor wordpess to clear rewrite cache

Comment: I do a clean installation of WordPress and WooCommerce and the result is the same. Url redirect to `http://localhost/page/2/`. I always resave permalinks after this action. My permalink structure is set to Post name -> `http://localhost/%postname%/` Shop base page slug is set to obchod.

Comment: Here is my demo and a link to the pagination http://orbitalis.beget.tech/summer/obchod/strana/2/

Can you send me a link to your demo or its on localhost?